# Raspberry PI - Python Network NAME

Tags: python, networking, pi

I've made a small info / kiosk system where a user can scan a QR code on the screen to connect with the raspberry pi. On the screen (next to the QR code) I want to put the name of the network (because you have to be on the same network to have the interaction).

How can I print the name of the network (wifi or cable) on the screen, the IP address is not the issue, neither the hostname. I am just struggling with the name of the network where the Pi is connected too..

Thanks

Comment: Networks do not have names. If you mean the SSID name, that is only for Wi-Fi, but that is not really the name of the network because networks do not have names.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Is there a way to detect if you are using wifi or cable network?

Comment: The real way to distinguish networks is by the network address. You mask (bitwise `AND`) the interface address with the network mask, and the result is the network address, which is the real name of the network. In any case, physical, data-link, network, and transport layers do not use names, the last three use addressing, e.g. MAC addressing, IP addressing, and port addressing. Other or no addressing in different of those layers is possible with other protocols, but none use names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cabled networks often don't have a name as WiFi networks do. The name here would be simply the network adapter it is connected with.

For WiFi I'd parse the output of `iwconfig` on Linux or `netsh <adaptername> show interfaces` on Windows. Take a look at the [wifi](https://pypi.org/project/wifi/) extension on PyPi.